# Property 'GoogleAuthProvider' does not exist on type 'Auth'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

In my **auth.service.ts**, when I add sign in with google, it gave me an error saying that `Property 'GoogleAuthProvider' does not exist on type 'Auth'. ts(2339)`.

This is the code written in **auth.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private afAuth: Auth) { }

  googleSignIn() {
    const provider = new this.afAuth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }

  async getUser() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Comment: You maybe using the wrong import path, maybe you can try this https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md ```import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';``` And correct your constructor to ```constructor(public afauth: AngularFireAuth)```

Comment: @Photonic It is saying that `Property 'GoogleAuthProvider' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.`

Comment: Try installing ```ng add @angular/fire```